# group element by two python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, list-comprehension

I want to write elements by group of 2 from a list into a txt file using list comprehension.

```
datacolumn =    ['A1', -86, 'A2', 1839, 'A3', 2035, 'A4', 1849, 'A5', 1714, ...]
```

so that filename.txt =

```
A1 -86
A2 1839
A3 2035
A4 1849
A5 1714
...
```

I found a solution  for writing element as one column :

```
with  open('filename.txt','w') as f:
     f.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in datacolumn)
```

but I can't figure out how to do this for two elements at a time. I did it with a loop :

```
with  open('filename.txt','w') as f:
     for i in range(0,size(datacolumn),2):
            f.write(str(datacolumn[i])+"\t"+str(datacolumn[i+1])+"\n")
```

but I would prefer to use a comprehension list. I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
res = [ "{}\t{}\n".format(x,y) 
          for (x,y) in zip(datacolumn[0::2], datacolumn[1::2])]
```

...will give you a list of rows, formatted as you seem to require.

Note that it assumes that there are even pairs to format.

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks a lot that's perfect, I could then write to the text file using your code :   f.writelines("{}\t{}\n".format(x,y) \
for (x,y) in zip(datacolumn[0::2], datacolumn[1::2]))

Answer (score 0):

I am using the temporary lists a and b to store the elements in the even and odd indices respectively.

```
datacolumn =    ['A1', -86, 'A2', 1839, 'A3', 2035, 'A4', 1849, 'A5', 1714]  
a=[datacolumn[x] for x in range(10) if x%2==0]
b=[datacolumn[x] for x in range(10) if x%2==1]
size=10
f=open("test.txt","w")
for i in range(size/2):
   f.write( a[i]+"\t" + str(b[i])+"\n")
```

Hope it helped. You can find more about list comprehensions [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I also thought of using two different temporary list but @Joachim Isaksson gave me the answer with a comprehension list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ipartition](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#ipartition) function from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library:

```
from funcy import ipartition

with open('filename.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines('%s %d\n' % (label, num) 
                 for label, num in ipartition(2, datacolumn))
```